# How to get a text from a DataInteraction object

Tags: android, android-espresso, dataadapter

I am testing an android application in which I want to retrieve the text from a `datainteraction` object. Is there any code to do the same.
Below is the sample code which i did.

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.procedureListView)).atPosition(i).onChildView(withId(R.id.workOrderStatus))).toString()
```

When I tried to run the code, it returns some random `datainteraction` object string which is not the expected one.

Comment: could you post also a screenshot and highlight what you want to test on that screen?